# Why aren't certain prefix and infix operators included in the parsing rules table in the "Crafting Interpreters" parser?

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction

In Bob Nystrom's [Crafting Interpreters](https://www.craftinginterpreters.com/compiling-expressions.html), the author creates his parser using a function pointer table where the main parsing function `parsePrecedence()` looks up a particular rule in the table and calls the function in the table. This makes sense for unary arithmetic operators like negation, or binary arithmetic operators like addition and multiplication. However, once [global variables](https://www.craftinginterpreters.com/global-variables.html) come into the mix, I no longer understand. For instance, why is the function `varDeclaration()` not placed in the `TOKEN_VAR` slot in the table? Wouldn't it count as a prefix operator? And why isn't the assignment operator inserted into the table and considered as an infix operator?

Comment: Such choices are entirely arbitrary. Not every token's precedence needs to be taken care of using the precedence table you speak of. Parsers can handle precedence in a number of ways. The table you speak of is just to help visualize relative precedence of certain constructs, not of every single reduction rule.

Comment: Not everything is an operator, and a declaration isn't an expression.  In particular the `=` sign in a definition with an initializer is not the `=` operator.

Comment: @Nate: But Nystrom's code does parse assignment expressions -- his words -- in a way which avoids the precedence mechanism he uses for other operators. His text explains why.

Comment: @rici: Where is this explanation? Can you quote the beginning of it for me? Perhaps I missed it when I read the chapter through.

Comment: @nanoman: Yeah, I was writing an answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Nystrom explains (in the [page which you cited](https://www.craftinginterpreters.com/global-variables.html#assignment)) the reason why assignment operators are special-cased in his parser:

> Our bytecode VM uses a single-pass compiler. It parses and generates bytecode on the fly without any intermediate AST. As soon as it recognizes a piece of syntax, it emits code for it.

If the parser were building an AST as an intermediate representation, there would be no problem parsing all operators in the same generic fashion. But since he needs to emit correct byte-code *as soon as the assignment is detected*, he cannot use the generic framework, because that will emit code to *look up the value* of the thing on the left-hand side of the assignment operator, and the code which is required is code to set that value.

As for variable declarations (and other statements which start with keywords), it might be possible to use operator precedence techniques to parse them, but since the syntax which follows the keyword is not generally an expression, and because the keyword cannot generally be used as a value inside an expression, the operator-precedence parser would need a lot of special-casing to produce the correct parse. Still, there are language parsers which use operator-precedence parsing for everything, so it is possible. But it's not necessarily the most convenient.

Comment: "......because the keyword cannot generally be used as a value inside an expression......"
When you wrote that, I understand some of the cases. Things like `5 + var name` would be disallowed. But then if you look at the final table (https://github.com/munificent/craftinginterpreters/blob/master/c/compiler.c#L871) you'll see that `this` and `super` are oddly enough _inside_ the table. But things like `this + 2` should also be disallowed. Then why are those in the table and not something like `if` or `var`?

Comment: @nanoman: what's wrong with `this + 2`? Isn't `this` a value?

Comment: @nanoman: `5 + var name` would certainly be wrong. But so would `var name + 5`. `var` is simply not an expression. The thing about operator-precedence parsing is that it only works on a collection of rules where all the non-terminals have the same syntactic type. If some are expressions and others are statements, for example, operator-precedence starts to get messy. It can be done, but making good error messages is harder.

Comment: wouldn't `this +2` not work if, say, `this` was actually an object of some sort? An object with multiple components shouldn't be added on, yes? Imagine if a user decided on making a `Token` object in Lox. What would `this + 2` refer to?

Comment: @nanoman: I don't know anything about his language and I'm not too inclined to read through it's semantics, but these days most languages have C++-like mechanisms which allow extending `+` to other datatypes. Anyway, if `+` isn't defined for a value it's applied to, that's a semantic error, not a syntax error. (`a + 2` wouldn't be a syntax error if `a` happened to refer to a struct of some sort, right?)